# What must the first character of an XML file be?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shebang

Specifically, is there a way to write a shebang for an XML file?

I'm working with some XML files that contain launch information. (Roslaunch files, if it matters). I would like to call the file directly and have bash launch it.  However, to XML, starting with `#!` is a syntax error.  Is there any way to write an XML file with a shebang?

Comment: Are you talking about having your `XML` launch a bash script? IE `<ACTION>/path/to/your/script.sh</ACTION>`

Comment: In this case, it is roslaunch.  I currently run `roslaunch file.launch` where file.launch is the XML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first character in an XML file ***must*** be `<` or whitespace.  A well-formed XML document may begin with no other character, including `#`.

Per the [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) XML EBNF for [***Well-Formed XML Documents***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed):

> ```
> [1]  document ::= prolog element Misc*
> [22] prolog   ::= XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?
> [23] XMLDecl  ::= '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
> [27] Misc     ::= Comment | PI | S
> [3]  S        ::= (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
> [16] PI       ::= '<?' PITarget (S (Char* - (Char* '?>' Char*)))? '?>'
> [15] Comment  ::= '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
> [28] doctypedecl ::= '<!DOCTYPE' S Name (S ExternalID)? S? 
>                      ('[' intSubset ']' S?)? '>'
> [39] element  ::= EmptyElemTag | STag content ETag
> [44] EmptyElemTag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'
> [40] STag     ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
> ```

As is evident from the `document` production and its constituent parts, an XML document must start with either:

- a `<` (via an `XMLDecl`, `Comment`, `PI`, `doctypedecl`, or `element`) ***or***
- a whitespace character (provided there is no `XMLDecl`).

Comment: Dang. I was hoping that there was an alternate way to do the shebang or something.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to find another solution such as writing a wrapper that reads in or embeds the XML.  There simply is no way to have a well-formed XML file start with `#!`.   Hopefully this at least spares you further time investigating an impossible approach.

Comment: Is there a way to have a shebang that calls a program that stirps the shebang before passing it?

Comment: That wouldn't be an XML file then but does get back to the idea mentioned in my previous comment about embedding the XML in another file (such as a shell script).

Answer (score 0):

With bash, a shebang needs not start with `#!`.  A neat trick is to use whatever the script uses for comments and define it as a no-op function, then follow that function with a semicolon, *then* the interpreter name.

This doesn't work for XML scripts because a redirection cannot be an identifier.

Comment: Could you give an example or a link to documentation. I'm not sure how to implement this from your description.

Comment: --()[ :;};psql -f

Comment: So the line is a comment in psql, but bash runs it as a bash code, which starts the file?